# Assign zeros to large list of indexed variables

Tags: list-manipulation, index

I have a big list of the form

```
list={P[1,1],..,P[i,j]}
```

and would like to assign 0 to each of them, but

```
list=ConstantArray[0,Length[list]]
```

doesn't work. While it does work for lists that aren't indexed the way I have them... I tried doing a `Do` loop but with the size of the list it's extremely slow.

Answer (score 7):

You could use

```
Evaluate[list] = ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]
```

or

```
MapThread[Set, {list, ConstantArray[0, Length[list]]}]
```

to `Set` each indexed variable inside of `list` to 0.

If the indexes for the variables inside `list` follow a known condition, one can use for example

```
p[i_ /; i < 3, j_ /; j < 5] = 0
```

or memorization

```
p[i_ /; i < 3, j_ /; j < 5] := p[i, j] = 0
```